# When a type is `Copy` should a method move (`self`) or borrow (`&self`) the type?

Tags: rust, move, borrow-checker, dereference, borrow

In Rust, when a type is [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), should a method move (`self`) or borrow (`&self`) the type?

When a method from a non-`Copy` type is called, there is a significant difference between a move (`self`) and a borrow (`&self`). For example, you would not be able to call a method that uses move (`self`) twice. However, for a `Copy` type, the difference between a move (`self`) and a borrow (`&self`) becomes less significant, at least for the caller.

In addition, as Rust will automatically [dereference or borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) to look up a method, you can call a move (`self`) method or a reference (`&self`) method in the exact same manner.

I expect that there is little difference in each approach. When inlined by the Rust compiler, both appear to generate identical assembly code. At least from [my experiment](https://godbolt.org/z/6nM3EKvvj) on the [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) compiler explorer. However, when [not inlined](https://godbolt.org/z/Yj6orMdP3) the assembly code generated can be different. This is a trivial example, and therefore it should be taken with a grain of salt.

I couldn't establish a common practice from the standard library as there appears to be examples of both.

- [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html) uses both `self` and `&self`.
- [`IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html) uses `&self`.
- ['usize'](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html) uses `self`.

I don't think there should be much difference between each approach in the real world, although it does make me curious. Every time I implement `Copy` on a type, I wonder what the best approach is...

I did find [an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f6599252d320d356f52f37a54dc4194), whereby I must implement [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) for both a value and a reference, otherwise the example will not compile. I am sure there are many more examples that exhibit similar behaviour, which may therefore make it more desirable to implment methods for either move (`self`) or borrow (`&self`).

*What do you think is best? Does it matter? Is there a standard approach? Are there other cases that I should consider?*

EDIT: At the moment I prefer to use a move (`self`) for `Copy` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rule of thumb is:

- If, when implementing on a non-`Copy` type, this method will consume `self`, do the same for `Copy` types, because it is clearer and more uniform this way. An example of this is the arithmetic methods on `Duration`, e.g. `checked_add()`.
- If not, then: for small types (when one machine bytes (up to usize) is definitely small, and two are usually small because they're passed in pair of registers, but three are already big because they're passed on stack) that are expected to stay small in future versions, take `self` by value because it is faster this way; for other types (big or that may become big) take `&self`, because taking `self` will force a copy and will be (somewhat) slower.

  An example of the first type is all methods on integers and floats and chars (well, almost all of them, some in `char` take `&self` for legacy reasons). An example of the second type is methods on `Duration` or `IpAddr`.

`From` is a different story; it makes sense to implement it for both owned and references.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What makes `From` different? I couldn't quite understand why Rust wouldn't automatically [dereference or borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) it. The documentation appears to indicate the compiler should build a list of all "candidate receiver types" and try also search methods in any "visible traits".

Comment: Also, in the case of `Duration` which is a `u64` and a `u32`, do you think all of its methods should've been implemented with `self`, instead of only some such as `checked_add`. Maybe it would be desirable to change, but cannot as it would now be a breaking change?

Comment: @scottwillmoore What makes `From` different? The fact that it is not autorefed. And about `Duration`, not necessarily; many times passing a pair of scalars by value is faster because they're passed in registers, but not always. For one scalar, passing by value is _always_ cheaper than passing by reference.

Comment: @scottwillmoore And also consider 32-bit platforms, where `u64` is not a scalar. Usually we don't account for them, but std should be for everyone. Now, this is only matter of nanoseconds, so this probably doesn't matter much: it's just a good habit.

Comment: Just to follow up (maybe this should be a separate question), could you expand on why `From` not "autorefed". From the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) it appears as if it should. My logic is: A "list of candidate receiver types" is built which should contain `Card`, `Card` and `&Card` when called by value or reference. For each of these types, the `Into<char>::into()` method is looked up as it is a "visible trait". Therefore, shouldn't we only require `From` to be implemented by value or reference?

Comment: I decided to ask this as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76478569/7349225).

Comment: Taking `self` doesn't have to necessarily copy the value. With optimizations a `fn([u8; 16])` actually passes in a pointer, so it's equivalent to `fn(&[u8; 16])`. See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1a7de1b9e7571465f2e500863f3f087f). The compiler should be the one responsible for optimizing how the value is passed at the machine code level. The rust code should only care about ownership, which is irrelevant with `Copy` types, so `self` should always be used.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues It passes as pointer (which is exactly what I said: it passes on stack and not in registers), but the caller has to copy it and it is very rarely eliminated: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/899cvqq9h. Whether to care about that or not is another matter, and unless the type is big it _probably_ doesn't matter, but why not do it better?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I didn't think that calling `takes_array` would need to copy it, since it's already receiving a pointer from the caller's stack. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues For `Copy` types they must copy, because the function may change them and it must change the copy. LLVM could theoretically optimize copies more in a lot of cases, but it refuses to do mainly because of address stability.