# Why do I need to implement `From` for both a value and a reference? Shouldn't methods be automatically dereferenced or borrowed?

Tags: rust, reference, traits, dereference, coercion

The behaviour of a Rust method call is described in [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html). It states that "when looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method." The behaviour is explained in more detail further into the chapter.

In the example, you can see that `into_char` moves `Suit`, while `to_char` borrows `Suit`.

- `into_char`, it is called by a value and a reference, and the reference is automatically dereferenced.
- `to_char`, it is also called by a value and a reference, and the value is automatically borrowed.

`From` is implemented for both a value and a reference of `Suit`. Therefore, when called by a value `Into<Suit>::into()` is called, and when called by a reference `Into<&Suit>::into()` is called.

*However, shouldn't I only need to implement one of these traits? When I comment out either implementation the Rust compiler does not compile...*

The process appears to be as follows... First generate a list of "candidate receiver types". This is obtained by "repeatedly dereferencing", and finally "attempting an unsized coercion at the end". In addition, "for each candidate T, add &T and &mut T to the list immediately after T." Then, for each of these "candidate receiver types" look for "methods implemented directly on T" and "methods provided by a visible trait implemented by T".

Consider that just `From<Suit>` is implemented for `char`. Then `Into<Suit>` should be implemented for `char`.

- When `let c: char = value.into();` is called, the "candidate receiver types" should contain at least `Suit` `&Suit` and `&mut Suit`. Then, `Into<T>::into()` is easily resolved for the first item in the list. Hence, `Into<Suit>::into()` is called.
- But, when `let f: char = reference.into();` is called, the "candidate receiver types" should also contain at least `&Suit`, `&&Suit`, `&mut &Suit`, `*&Suit = Suit`, `&Suit` (again) and `&mut Suit`. Then `Into<T>::into()` cannot find an implemented for `&Suit`, `&&Suit` and `&mut &Suit`, but does then find an implementation for `*&Suit = Suit`. Hence, `Into<Suit>::into()` is called.

*Is my logic correct? Why doesn't this work if I comment-out one of the `From` implementations?*

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a03c959bb2b4ae39d086c5c863bca99)

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Suit {
    Club,
    Diamond,
    Heart,
    Spade,
}

pub use Suit::*;

impl Suit {
    #[inline(never)]
    pub fn into_char(self) -> char {
        match self {
            Club => 'C',
            Diamond => 'D',
            Heart => 'H',
            Spade => 'S',
        }
    }
    
    #[inline(never)]
    pub fn to_char(&self) -> char {
        match self {
            Club => 'C',
            Diamond => 'D',
            Heart => 'H',
            Spade => 'S',
        }
    }
}

impl std::convert::From<Suit> for char {
    fn from(suit: Suit) -> Self {
        suit.into_char()
    }
}

impl std::convert::From<&Suit> for char {
    fn from(suit: &Suit) -> Self {
        suit.to_char()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let value = Club;
    let reference = &value;
    
    let a: char = value.into_char();
    let b: char = value.to_char();
    let c: char = value.into();
    println!("{}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
    
    let d: char = reference.into_char();
    let e: char = reference.to_char();
    let f: char = reference.into();
    println!("{}, {}, {}", d, e, f);
}
```

EDIT: As discussed below, I created a [better reproduction](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b46d12ea13f660bc87ea09e90315daa) of the problem, which does help narrow down what causes this behaviour.

EDIT: I have created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/112951) for the Rust compiler.

Comment: My guess is that it *does* find an implementation, but it's `impl<T> From<T> for T`, and then it tries to assign `Suit` and `char` both to `T` and it fails.

Comment: That does seem to be the case. Look at what happens when you uncomment the commented part: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d81bd160597bc7d595c49ec43dca294d

Comment: Very weird. It does seem to be the blanket trait implementation that causes this issue. I created my [own example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b46d12ea13f660bc87ea09e90315daa), and it appears to work for a one-parameter `<T>` blanket implementation, but not for the two-parameter `<T, U>` implementation. *Should this be further investigated? Perhaps it is an issue on the Rust repository needs to be raised?*

Comment: Just for the record, because `Suit: Copy`, you can call `into_char()` on a reference. You don't need the separate `to_char()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when matching traits the compiler does not take later inference types into account. So, while we know that `into()` is expected to produce `B`, the compiler doesn't know that yet. So all it sees is that we want an implementation of `Into` `Suit as Into<_>`, for *some* type `_`. Because it doesn't know what type `_` is, this matches `impl<U, T: From<U>> Into<T> for U`, seen by the compiler as `Into<_> for _`, as it is unable to verify the `where T: From<U>` because `_` can be any type. So the compiler picks this implementation (which has higher priority because it does not use autoref) and does not search further for `impl Into<_> for &Suit`.

Later, when the compiler comes back to this decision, armed with the knowledge that we expect a `char`, it realizes that this impl no longer match - but it doesn't go back to search impls for autoref types; it is done with that. So we end up with no matching impl.

Comment: Yes, thank you. For those who want a concrete example, I've carefully documented [this reproduction](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ff58178f7a0b9c9e5a7a15d38dde93f) which what I believe is the process used by the compiler. *Do you think this can be fixed? Would it be possible to update the compiler to continue the search when a match is not found?* I guess this would be a breaking change, and therefore would need to be left for a new Rust edition. *Is it worth raising this issue in the Rust repository?*

Comment: @scottwillmoore I don't believe this is a breaking change, and I believe it can be fixed, although I don't know how hard it is to fix this. You can definitely open an issue.